# The height of the menu is not correct CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working in a home page, it's working correctly, but the menu on the left sidebar, it's not making and overflow correctly. I need the scrollbars on the menu, 'cause I don't want it on the page.

I think the issue it's with the height, but I need the 100% of the height not in pixels, somebody can help me?[image]

Here you are de JsBin: http://jsbin.com/ceyij

Comment: remove overflow:hidden from body tag in css @luiggi

Comment: ".sidebar-menu" class have a fixed height of 780px.

Comment: Looks like inline styles(min-height) are adding dynamically for html and body.

Comment: I remo the fixed height, and the styles from js :((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the best result with the following  thanks to jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Handler for .ready() called.

    var alt = $(".wrapper").height();
    $(".left-side").height(alt);
    $(".sidebar").height(alt - 153);
    var altHeader = $("header.header").height();
    $(".sidebar-menu").height(alt - 153);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

In `ceyij.css`, you have given `height:99% !important` in html and body tag
and also give `overflow:hidden` so
just remove height 99% and give `overflow:auto` instead of hidden
it not proper look like

Comment: I don't want the scrollbar on the page, just on the sidebar menu :((

Comment: use have to set height of wrapper like (window height - header height)

Comment: and aslo set height .sidebar class to (side section - side section header) using jquery

Comment: @Luiggi u have just remove height 99% and oveflow from html tag

Answer (score 1):

It is because you have only given 99% height to your `html`.Just make it `100%`

Comment: @Luiggi:Could you please put the code in a fiddle or something

Comment: @Luiggi:have you modified something :).Now am not abel t o see the scroll at all

Answer (score 1):

In order for an element to have 100% height, the parent element that wraps it must also have either a fixed or percentage height.

So with that in mind you will need 100% heights on both the **HTML** and **BODY** tags like this:

```
html, body 
{
height:100%;
width:100%;
}
For the particular list items 
#menu_panel {
height:100%;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: no dude. i just write up for your ref '#menu_panel' id if you can make it change for your required